# Ruby: Push item to Marshal or JSON without deserializing?

Tags: ruby, json, serialization, marshalling

Is it possible to serialize an array in either JSON or Marshal and push serialized items onto the end of the serialized array? Or am I forced to deserialize the array, push the item, then re-serialize it?

Something that would work like this (or in JSON)?

```
x = [1,2,3]
serial = Marshal.dump(x)
serial << Marshal.dump([4])
Marshal.load(serial)
=> [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: In principle, it should be possible, but I don't think it is practical. It would be more complicated than doing it in Ruby. Why cannot you do that within Ruby and then serialize it at once?

Comment: I'm using Redis. I will have TONS of large sets that I'm going to attempt to serialize instead (and use Redis strings instead of sets). It would be very convenient for me to just push serialized items on the end of the string rather than getting the string, deserializing, pushing, re-serializing and setting it.

Comment: If you have to constantly deserialize and re-serialize your strings then you ar probably not using Redis appropriately. As I have not used it I can not advise you on a proper model, but you should consider adding Redis to the question as a tag. Given you seem to *want* to use JSON a to store your data you should also consider switching to JSON stores such as MongoDB or CouchDB.

Comment: @Patru Inspiration taken from here: http://blog.skillpages.com/using-redis-as-primary-database/

Comment: Interesting read, thanks for the pointer. Notice however, that they only did this kind of optimization *after* measuring the performance of their system. Obviously the time to deserialize the list, change it an re-serialize it did not matter to the status update request, but the renormalization served their most important aggregation query. *If* you have similar query characteristics (possibly measured) *then* you probably should take this route.